# Cache Image From URL working, but returns blank image?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage, nsdata

I have two methods, first checks if I've already downloaded the image, and if not retrieves the image from a URL and caches it to my docs directory in my app. If it has been, it simply retrieves it, and if I have a internet connection, will re-download it. Here are the two methods:

```
- (UIImage *) getImageFromUserIMagesFolderInDocsWithName:(NSString *)nameOfFile
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:nameOfFile];
    if (!image) // image doesn't exist in bundle...
    {
        // Get Image
        NSString *cleanNameOfFile = [[[nameOfFile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""]
                                                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]
                                                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];

        NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.png", cleanNameOfFile]];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
        if (!image)
        {
            // image isn't cached
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nameOfFile]]];
            [self saveImageToUserImagesFolderInDocsWithName:cleanNameOfFile andImage:image];
        }
        else
        {
            // if we have a internet connection, update the cached image
            /*if (isConnectedToInternet) {
                image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nameOfFile]]];
                [self saveImageToUserImagesFolderInDocsWithName:cleanNameOfFile andImage:image];
            }*/
            // otherwise just return it
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

Here's to save the image

```
- (void) saveImageToUserImagesFolderInDocsWithName:(NSString *)nameOfFile andImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSString *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.png", nameOfFile]];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];


    NSLog(@"directory: %@", [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pngPath]);
}
```

The image has already been successfully downloaded and cached to my documents directory (I know because I can see it in the File system). And it successfully re loads the image the first time I call this method, but once I go to another view, and re-call this method when I come back to the same view, it's blank. Yet, the URL is correct. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should not be writing into a hardcoded path as you do (ie "Documents/xxx"), but rather ask for the Application Support directory, use it, and also mark files so that they don't get uploaded to iCloud (unless you want that). See [this link on the specifics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371323/1633251). Create a subfolder in it and mark it as not for iCloud backup.

2) Try changing:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nameOfFile]]];
```

to

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should do:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: nameOfFile];
```

Comment: I've tried that as well (in place of returning it as nsdata then initializing it) same thing happens.

Comment: Have you tracked `filePath` and `pngPath` variables?