# How To write into text File at my application's bundle in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

beg-counter.txt file is already in my application's bundle....now i wanted to write into it...but i can't....

i can read that file but not able to write into it....

here is my code.......

value of level_beg_cnt is suppose 2.

NSError *error;

NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beg_counter" ofType:@"txt"];

```
    NSLog(@"string to write:%@",level_cnt_beg);




    [level_cnt_beg writeToFile:Path atomically:YES
                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: YOU CAN'T. Its read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle is read-only. You don't want to mess around with it for two reasons:

Code Signing: the signature is verified by against the contents of the bundle; if you mess around with the bundle, you break the signature.

App Updates: updates work by replacing the entire app bundle with a newly downloaded one; any changes you make will get lost.

Where you should save stuff:

Documents: if you want it to persist and be backed up

Library/Caches: if you just want to cache downloaded data, like profile pics; will be auto deleted by the system if it is low on room unless you specify with a special do-not-delete flag.

tmp: temporary files, deleted when your app is not running
For a full explanation check out File System Programming Guide and QA1719.

From following SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679448/does-an-ios-app-have-write-access-inside-its-bundle):

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to applications bundle, it is read-only,

You can write files to document directory.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]; // or [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"beg_counter.txt"];

[level_cnt_beg writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

you can also save files to `temp` directory and `Library`directory, for more info read this documentation, [Where you should put your files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28)

Thanks

Comment: and if i want to write text file at any location but not at the document directory....then what would i do?