# How to replace the contents of a bundled file

Tags: ios, swift

I want to replace the contents of a JSON file with data coming from an API call.  I have tried the following:

```
let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "shared", ofType: "json")!
let fileUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

do {
    try jsonData.write(to: fileUrl, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

    do {
        let newData = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl, encoding: .utf8)
        print("New Data: \(newData)")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to read updated file data")
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to write data to file")
}
```

I've confirmed that "shared.json" is listed under "Copy Bundle Resources".  I'm not getting any errors.  Yet the contents of "shared.json" never changes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you can get a `URL` to a bundled file directly with one function, `Bundle.main.url(forResource: withExtension:)`, there's no need to convert the path to a `URL` manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679524/1361672

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Files embed in your app cannot be edited. At first install, you have to copy your embedded files into the Documents directory and then edit this version.